# How to write a Single line sed command to print out SSN that start at the beginning of the line and are followed by a space

Tags: sed

So i'm trying to get Only SSN that start the line. 
Here is what the sample data would look like.

```
111-11-1111 dfsfdsfsdfafdfsfdsdsfsfdfsda
dsffdsdsfdfsf 222-22-2222 dfsfsdafasasdadas
 333-33-3333 dsfadfasdasdfa
444-44-4444 fdfdfsfdsfs
555-55-5555
dfsfdfdffffdsdfsfdsfsd 66-66-6666
```

So only the 1,4 and 5 SSN should print out and nothing else. This would be easy in awk or even a sed script, But i need to do it in a one line sed command(Reviewing a test question i missed for a class).

I've tried.

```
sed 's/.*\(^[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\).*/\1/'
```

which gives me

```
111-11-1111
dsffdsdsfdfsf 222-22-2222 dfsfsdafasasdadas
 333-33-3333 dsfadfasdasdfa
444-44-4444
555-55-5555
dfsfdfdffffdsdfsfdsfsd
```

However i can't get the rest of the lines(2,3,6) deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for `sed`, `grep` is better at extracting simple data :

```
grep -Eo '^[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}( |$)'
```

This however includes a trailing space, which could be avoided by the use of PCRE's lookaheads :

```
grep -Po '^[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}(?= |$)'
```

If you really want to use `sed`, the following should work with BSD and recent GNU `sed` (in older GNU `sed`, use `-r` instead of `-E`) :

```
sed -nE 's/^([0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4})( |$).*/\1/p'
```

It uses the `-n` flag so that lines won't be printed by default, and the `p` command at the end of the substitution so that matched lines will be printed.

I had to make `$` (which matches the end of the string) and alternative to the space to match the 4th line.

Comment: I guess you should write `3`, `2`, `4`

Comment: @Kent indeed, thank you. Also made the end of the string an alternative to the space